# How to call a method defined in another module in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, module

```
class Foo
  include Bar
  include Baz
end

module Bar
  def do_something
  end
end

module Baz
  do_something
end
```

`Baz` module does not have access to `Bar`. Is there a way for it to call a method in `Bar`?

One approach is to *extend* `Baz` with `Bar`, but I want to *include* them all in `Foo` instead.

Comment: Because `do_something` is only called from Baz.

Answer (score 2):

If for whatever reason you don't want to *extend* `Baz` with `Bar`, you can create an *object* that *extends* `Bar` inside `Baz`:

```
module Bar
  def do_something
    puts 42
  end
end

module Baz
  Object.new.extend(Bar).do_something # prints 42
end
```